# Cocoa/Obj-C Path Control - Can you restrict it to only select directories?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, path

I'm learning to write Mac programs and am looking at the Path Control object. I need to restrict its selections to only directories and not files.

Is there a way to do this? Is there a special keyword to put in the Legal Types box that means "directories"? I tried "Folder" and "Directory" but they don't work.

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't actually tried this, but it seems like you might be able to call `-[NSPathCell setAllowedTypes:]`, specifying public.folder as the only allowed UTI.

In response to a comment asking for more detail on where it is supposed to go:  If you have an outlet to an `NSPathControl`, you could set this programmatically like so:

```
[[myPath cell] setAllowedTypes: [NSArray arrayWithObject: @"public.folder"]];
```

Comment: I didn't actually use that code because I wasn't sure where it's supposed to go (I'm still quite confused about the whole interface, implementation, delegate etc.) HOWEVER you did solve the problem! Turns out the file type for restricting to folders is the same in the GUI interface builder so I added the 'public.folder' UTI and it worked! I'll read up on the documentation for NSPathCell so I know where to stick that in future.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Setting `Legal Types` in Interface Builder to only allow `public.folder` works for me.